# vendor/config.php has database settings, how do I regenerate this?

Tags: laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5 project that I copied to a new folder. I changed the database settings in the .env file. But now I am concluding that database settings are also set in vendor/config.php. What command must I run to have this regenerated? I already tried `composer dump-autoload` and `composer update` without success

Comment: "But now I am concluding that database settings are also set in vendor/config.php." Why have you concluded that? What problem are you actually encountering?

Comment: I don't know how that came there, but it keeps using that config file. While my database.php and .env were adapted to the new environment. Found a solution though. Just deleted the whole vendor directory and ran `composer update` for all vendor files to be redownloaded

Answer (score 0):

The [default database config](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/database.php) is in `config/database.php` and looks in `.env` for its settings (with some fallback defaults). For example, the default MySQL connection:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Laravel does not have a `vendor/config.php` file.